# matplotlib/pyplot - make axes (ordinate and abscissa) bold

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Is there a way to make the x=0 and y=0 (the ordinate and abscissa) axes in a Cartesian plot bold?

For example, a simple plot is:

```
x = np.arange(0.01, 5, 0.1)
y = np.log(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I can add this 'hack':

```
x = np.arange(0.01, 5, 0.1)
y = np.log(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()

plt.plot(x,0*x, 'k')
plt.plot(x*0,x, 'k')
plt.plot(x*0,-x, 'k')
```

Then I get:

[image]

Is there a way to make this a bit less hacky - an API or a more sophisticated solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 9))
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.axhline(y=0, lw=5, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, lw=5, color='k')
```

[image]
From a practical view, I always use artist to make matplotlib plots, making adjustment of properties much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer, I would add to it that you can also pass `color` (e.g. `color='k'`) in the `axhline` and `axvline` keywords to keep it black, if you want, in addition to tweaking lw to set the linewidth to your choosing